# Query slow while using like in text column with OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables RequestHistoryLog and Request.

RequestHistoryLog table have these columns with 1.2 million of rows

```
id(bigint), status(VARCHAR), byUser(VARCHAR),
            delegatedUserFor(text), reqId(bigint)
reqId with CONSTRAINTS FOREIGN KEY (`reqId`) REFERENCES `Request` (`id`)
```

Request table have many columns with 0.4 million  of rows

```
id(bigint), title(VARCHAR), actionDateTime(Datetime), type(VARCHAR) etc.
```

In RequestHistoryLog there are multiple entries w.r.t status of a request.
And 1 Request has many LogHistory.

Here delegatedUserFor(is a text column type) has multiple names with emails.

```
Example is: 'X(x@xyz.com)A(a@xyz.com)Y(y@xyz.com)'
```

By the below query, I am trying to get the requests on which A(a@xyz.com) has done a status from "Approved", "Done", "Completed", "Queried", "Rejected" or
some other user has done a status for A(It means someone has done a status one-half of A) but this time entry goes to delegatedUserFor column.

```
SELECT *
    FROM  
        (SELECT r.*  
            FROM Request AS r  
            JOIN RequestHistoryLog AS rh ON r.id = rh.reqId  
            where  rh.status IN ("Approved", "Done", "Completed",
                                 "Queried", "Rejected")
              and  (rh.byUser='a@xyz.com'
                     or rh.delegatedUserFor like '%(a@xyz.com)%')
              and r.type='custom'
        ) AS a    
    GROUP BY id  
    ORDER BY actionDateTime desc limit 10;
```

I am writing a sample data for both table as:

```
RequestHistoryLog Table
id status     byUser          delegatedUserFor          reqId
2 "Approved" 'A(a@xyz.com)'  ''                         15
3 "Rejected" 'G(g@xyz.com)'  ''                         15
4 "Approved" 'X(x@xyz.com)'  'A(a@xyz.com)Y(y@xyz.com)' 15

5 "Approved" 'X(x@xyz.com)'  'G(g@xyz.com)A(a@xyz.com)Y(y@xyz.com)' 16
6 "Rejected" 'B(b@xyz.com)'  ''                                     16
7 "Completed"'Y(y@xyz.com)'  ''                                     16

Request Table
id  title      actionDateTime
15 "Request1" '2021-11-23 01:23:20' ..........
16 "Request2" '2021-11-23 11:23:20' ..........
```

Now I am getting requests on which A has done a status or other user has done one-half of A.

Above query is taking much time.

So I need how to optimize it to get fast result ?

Comment: Comma separated values is often the cause to various problems. Avoid!

Comment: @jarlh I know what you are saying but in our case We need data like this and not to use extra table for this column.

Comment: To be honest, I can’t believe you need data like this. If you need no extra table use JSON column instead. That’s much quicker then doing such strange things you do

Comment: `ON r.id = rh.reqId` -- Is this 1:1? or 1:many? or many:1?  (I'm wondering whether the `GROUP BY` is needed and is correct.)

Comment: @RickJames it is 1:many (Means 1 Request has many LogHistory) GROUP BY is correct when removing group it gives many duplicate rows of Requests.

Comment: I think it is slowing due to like  operator %email%. Is there anyway to do FTS(Full Text Search) on rh.delegatedUserFor ? Should it fast the result ? I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A:  (Probably better if not many rows are type=custom)**

Do a "semi-join":

```
SELECT r.*  
    FROM Request AS r  
    JOIN RequestHistoryLog AS rh ON r.id = rh.reqId
    WHERE r.type = 'custom'
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM RequestHistoryLog AS rh
                    WHERE r.id = rh.reqId
                      AND rh.status IN ("Approved", "Done", "Completed",
                             "Queried", "Rejected")
                      AND ( rh.byUser='a@xyz.com'
                           or rh.delegatedUserFor like '%(a@xyz.com)%' )
    ORDER BY r.actionDateTime desc
    LIMIT 10;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` and nested `SELECT` are avoided.  Have these indexes:

```
r:  INDEX(type, actionDateTime)
rh:  INDEX(reqId, status, byUser, delegatedUserFor)
```

**Plan B:  (if type is often =custom and/or 'xyz' is rare)**

```
FULLTEXT(byUser, delegatedUserFor)
```

and do

```
   WHERE MATCH(byUser, delegatedUserFor) AGAINST ("+xyz" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     AND  (rh.byUser='a@xyz.com'
         r rh.delegatedUserFor like '%(a@xyz.com)%')
```

This *should* find the rows with domain xyz first by FULLTEXT (rapidly), then verify against the other tests (against fewer rows).  Other simplifications can be done too.  Perhaps something like

```
SELECT r.*
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT rh.reqId
            FROM RequestHistoryLog AS rh
            WHERE MATCH ... AND ( ... OR ... )
              AND rh.status IN (...)
         ) AS x
    JOIN Request AS r  ON r.id = x.reqId  
    WHERE r.type = 'custom'
    ORDER BY r.actionDateTime desc
    LIMIT 10;
```

(No other indexes needed.)  The `GROUP BY` is replaced by `DISTINCT`, which is probably faster *in this case*.  And the `FULLTEXT` index *may* be very fast.

Note that FULLTEXT has a minimum word length (default 3), hence you need to avoid searching for "a" or any other string shorter than that.  Also "com" may be so common as to be not worth searching for.

**Plan C**

If there is some easy way to predict which one will be better, then have both queries and dynamically pick between them.

For example, when searching for `...@hp.com`, note that "hp" is too short, making the fulltext approach unworkable.

You probably know which r.type values occur more than 20% of the time, making the Plan B a better choice.

**Plan D: *if* only one domain**

If byUser and delegatedUserFor either have the same "xyz.com" or are blank, then add a column to `rh` replace the messy test with `AND rh.domain = 'xyz.com'`.  And still do something to get of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks Rick James for the above reply. I will explore both  which one will get the better and suitable result then let you know.Here type column has only three values "custom" , "template" , "Public".

Comment: @Ashraf - What is the frequency of each?

Comment: "custom" has lots many then "template" then "public" is very low.

Comment: So, Plan A for "public"; plan B for the others.